# c# datagridview show enum value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a winform application written in C#. To show the problem, I write the following code snippet.

```
class A
{
    public E e{get; set;}
}

enum E
{
    A=2,
    B=3
}

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    A[] AA=new A[]
           {
               new A{e=E.A},
               new A{}
           };
    dataGridView1.DataSource=AA;
}
```

I want it to show blank in the second row of the datagrid, but it generates an exception "System.ArgumentException: The value '0' is not a valid value for the enum 'E'.".
How can I deal with that? Basically the data are returned from others' programs which I can't change.

BTW, I have shown a single value in a propertyGrid. It works well. When the enum value is null, it shows a blank cell, which is just what I want. But datagrid works differently.

Comment: looks like the second `A` has no value for E and the enum has no default.

Comment: very good class name "A", enum "E" and array "A[] AA" ))) Its make it much more easies to read and to understand )

Comment: Can you change the class or enum?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn   No, I can't change the class or enum definition. They are provided by others as a library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you get that annoying dialog box that continually warns you with that exception as a message.  The workaround is to override that default behaviour by subscribing to the `DataGridView`'s `DataError` event and setting `e.ThrowException` to `false`.  However, since this is a bit of a hack to swallow an exception, you'll probably want to limit its scope to just the exception you're trying to swallow.  This is how I handled it.

```
private void DataGridView_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    var columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
    var valueType = dataGridView.Columns[columnIndex].ValueType;

    //HACK: Hides the infinitely-appearing error dialog for enum values which are not defined as fields in the enum.
    e.ThrowException = !typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(valueType) || Enum.IsDefined(valueType, dataGridView[columnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value);
}
```

So the dialog will appear if the `ValueType` of the cell in question is not assignable to an `Enum` or if the actual value is defined in the enum in question.

Answer (score -1):

Since you did not provide any value for E in the default constructor of the second element of the array, this variable E is initialized with 0 which is the default value of the int type. However, 0 is not in the set of the enum type, so the exception is thrown.

The solution is create a default constructor for the class A.

```
class A
{
    public A(){
        e = E.A; 
    }

    public E e{get; set;}
}
```